# How a dll is handled between different calls to an asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, dll, sharing

I am in the start of developing an `ASP.NET` application and want to decide how to cluster functions in different `dll`s.

Suppose that I have an `ASP.NET` page that has to `dll` *references*, namely **A.dll** and **B.dll**. However **B.dll** uses some methods of **A.dll**.

Having this scenario, if somebody call my `page.aspx` where it calls **B.dll**, another **A.dll** will be loaded to memory or **B.dll** will use the same **A.dll** loaded by my `page.aspx` ?

Answer (score 1):

Referenced libraries (`dll`) will be loaded when IIS is starting, some might be loaded on demand i'm not quite sure of that part. But none of your `dll`s would be loaded twice. `dll` is a code library, your code base containing definition of your implementation. Don't think of it as an `instance` of some custom class definition you made. Your `dll` might contain static classes, extension methods, helpers not only instantiable class definitions